# Google Test and boost::variant

Tags: boost, googletest, c++98

I wish to iterate over the types in my boost::variant within my unit test. This can be done as follows:

```
TEST_F (MyTest, testExucutedForIntsOnly)
{
    typedef boost::variant<int, char, bool, double> var;
    boost::mpl::for_each<SyntaxTree::Command::types>(function());
    ...
}
```

Where function is a functor. I simply want to ensure that a particular operation occurs differently for one type in the variant with respect to all others. However, I don't like that the test is now done in another function -- and what if I wish to access members for MyTest from the functor? It seems really messy.

Any suggestions on a better approach?

Comment: I need to be compatible with c++98

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to call a function on a boost::variant that is type-dependent?

Try this:

```
template<typename T>
struct RunOnlyOnType_Helper
{
  std::function<void(T)> func;
  template<typename U>
  void operator()( U unused ) {}
  void operator()( T t ) { func(t); }
  RunOnlyOnType_Helper(std::function<void(T)> func_):func(func_){}
};

template<typename T, typename Variant>
void RunOnlyOnType( Variant v, std::function< void(T) > func )
{
  boost::apply_visitor( RunOnlyOnType_Helper<T>(func), v );
}
```

The idea is that RunOnlyOnType is a function that takes a variant and a functor on a particular type from the variant, and executes the functor if and only if the type of the variant matches the functor.

Then you can do this:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, char, bool, double> var;
var v(int(7)); // create a variant which is an int that has value 7
std::string bob = "you fool!\n";
RunOnlyOnType<int>( v, [&](int value)->void
{
  // code goes here, and it can see variables from enclosing scope
  // the value of v as an int is passed in as the argument value
  std::cout << "V is an int with value " << value << " and bob says " << bob;
});
```

Is that what you want?

Disclaimer: I have never touched `boost::variant` before, the above has not been compiled, and this is based off of quickly reading the boost docs.  In addition, the use of `std::function` above is sub-optimal (you should be able to use templated functors all the way down -- heck, you can probably extract the type T from the type signature of the functor).

Comment: I need to be compatible with C++98 so I can't use lambdas :(